# ReactNative WebView not rendering on web, but works fine on Android

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

Used versions:

```
"expo": "^36.0.2",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.61.4",
"react-native-web": "0.11.7",
"react-native-webview": "^8.1.2"
```

Used React Native code:

```
<WebView
    source={{uri: 'https://www.somedomain.com/'}}
    style={{marginTop: 22, flex: 1}}
    injectedJavaScript={this.state.contentScript}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    onMessage={this.receiveMessage}
    ref={this.props.webview}
/>
```

Only a red border is present on the web version meanwhile on the Android it loads fine.

No errors present. Could this be a known issue? But I can't find it reported anywhere.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://github.com/react-native-web-community/react-native-web-webview

Answer (score 7):

Currently `WebView` is not supported by expo-web. Check [Platform Compatibility](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webview/) for more information.

But if you want to load your `WebView` inside expo-web, place it inside `iframe` as below,

```
import * as React from "react";
import { View, Platform } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return Platform.OS === "web" ? (
      <iframe src="https://www.somedomain.com/" height={'100%'} width={'100%'} />
    ) : (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: "https://www.somedomain.com/" }}
          style={{marginTop: 22, flex: 1}}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Ok so that makes sense. But sadly using the iframe with the same url results in an `Refused to display 'someurl' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".`. Funny that the WebView works fine for the url, it uses some different technique?

Comment: Well it does make sense of course hah, forgot I wasn't using chrome withou disabled security.

Comment: Hi, i had a webview rendering a html file using this path `http://LocalIPAddress/app/index.html?sessionId=${route.params.sessionId}` everything was working accordingly in development phase. To move to production, i had to add the index.html file to my backend. `http://SERVERIPADDRESS/api/html/index.html?sessionId=${route.params.sessionId}`. Now the url does not open inside the webview. Why is that?